# How customizable is vuetify data tables?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

I am trying to achieve the above result. I have already have the table working in my vue project.

This piece of code is the template for the datatable from Vuetify.

```
<v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            append-icon="mdi-magnify"
            label="Search"
            single-line
            hide-details
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="tableData"
          :search="search"
        ></v-data-table>
      </v-card>
```

Populating the table with basic data is just fine and I've already done that, but I need add that "Send again" link/button, and hook it up with a method. Or any other customization for that matter, like the yellow bullet point. Is this going to be super hard to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, we can use `item` or `item.<name>` Slots, you can read more about it in data table API https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots

your code can be something like this:

```
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
        
        <template v-if="item.status == `registered`">
          {{ item.status }} 
        </template>
        
        <template v-else>
          {{ item.status }} - <v-btn @click="AddSendBtnMethod(item.id)"> send again<v-btn>
        </template>
        
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/xxEQyOz) is a sample from Vuetify, changed to show how its works